# Redirecting output from a batch file, INCLUDING the commands

Tags: batch-file, command, redirect

I have a batch file that executes a series of commands. As each one executes, it returns either a "success" or "fail" message. Its simple enough to redirect the output from each of these using the >> and send it to a file, but without the associated command the output is useless.

(Batch File)

```
Command "D21" >> Myfile.txt
Command "D22" >> Myfile.txt
Command "D23" >> Myfile.txt
Command "D24" >> Myfile.txt
```

(Output file: Myfile.txt)

```
Fail
Succeed
Fail
Succeed
```

What I would like to do is also send the command that was executed to that file so it might look like this...

(Desired output file: Myfile.txt)

```
Command "D21" Fail
Command "D22" Fail
Command "D23" Succeed
Command "D24" Succeed
```

Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this with a minimum of effort?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take time when posting to properly format your code. You can do so by indenting at least four spaces, or by selecting all the code and either clicking the toolbar button that has the curly braces (`{}`) or pressing Ctrl+K. You can preview your post while entering it in somewhat WYSIWYG style directly below the text box, so you can properly format it real-time before posting. Also, please avoid using signatures in your posts; you have a profile page associated with your account that allows you to post personal information like your name. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

I presume you want to selectively redirect echoed commands and output within the batch, and not the whole batch.

```
@echo off
echo before not echoed, not captured
call :echoCommands >myFile.txt
echo after not echoed, not captured
exit /b

:echoCommands
echo on
Command "D21"
Command "D22"
Command "D23"
Command "D24"
@echo off
exit /b
```

If you want to capture the entire batch file, then simply remove the redirection from the script, don't turn echo off, and redirect when you call the batch script.

```
myScript >myFile.txt
```

If you want to capture the entire file output with commands, and you really want to redirect within the script, then something like

```
@if "%~1" neq "_GO_" (
  >myFile.txt call "%~f0" _GO_ %*
  exit /b
)
@echo on
Command "D21"
Command "D22"
Command "D23"
Command "D24"
```

In all of the solutions above, each command will be printed on one line, and the output will follow on the subsequent line(s).

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to put command and response on the same line

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=6 delims=" %%i in (%~dpnx0) do (
    <nul set /p =%%i >> MyFile.txt
    %%i >> MyFile.txt
)
goto :eof
Command "D21"
Command "D22"
Command "D23"
Command "D24"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. The first is a little "cryptic" but it gets it done in a one-line command:

```
for %%f in ("Command "D21"" "Command "D22"" "Command "D23"" "Command "D24"") do for /F "usebackq delims=" %%g in (`%%~f`) do echo %%~f %%g >> MyFile.txt
```

This should work just fine. It's just a little cubmersome to add more **`Command "xxx"`**'s.

The second way is to use a "subroutine" to handle the work:

```
@echo off

call :work Command "D21"
call :work Command "D22"
call :work Command "D23"
call :work Command "D24"
goto :EOF



:work
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%g in (`%*`) do echo %* %%g
goto :EOF
```